# Retrieving data from two chained many-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, database, join, many-to-many, table-relationships

I was practising with an example that I was creating like the one below (where I was thinking about a movie being able to belong to many categories and a category being able to belong to have many subcategories).

Not sure if chaining two many-to-many relationships is correct (I split them up in several one to many relationships), but when I'm making a query I'm getting pretty weird results.

Any clue how could I get movie title and genre name for all movies, even the ones without genre name? I'm using a query similar to this but it's not returning those titles :S

If I stop after the 1st many-to-many relationship, the results seem correct but once I add the 2nd relationship (with the query below), I don't receive anything... any suggestion pls?

```
SELECT movie.title, genre.name 
FROM movie 
LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_genre 
ON (movie.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id) 
JOIN genre 
ON (genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id) 
JOIN genre_subgenre 
ON (genre_subgenre.genre_id = genre.genre_id) 
JOIN subgenre 
ON (subgenre.subgenre_id = genre_subgenre.subgenre_id) 



+++++++++++++++++ 
+ Movie ID (PK) + 
+ Movie Title + 
+++++++++++++++++ 
| 
| 
| 
+++++++++++++++++ 
+ Movie ID (FK) + 
+ Genre ID (FK) + 
+++++++++++++++++ 
| 
| 
| 
+++++++++++++++++++ 
+ Genre ID (PK) + 
+ Genre Name + 
+++++++++++++++++++ 
| 
| 
| 
++++++++++++++++++++ 
+ Genre ID (FK) + 
+ Subgenre ID (FK) + 
++++++++++++++++++++ 
| 
| 
| 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
+ Subrenre ID (PK) + 
+ Subgenre Name (FK) + 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: I see only threee entity and you dind't provide us tables name. Please, try to be more accurate

Comment: Have you tried other joins as LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me propose sample data to see if I get it right:

- Movies: "Saw", "Twilight", "Platoon"
- Genre: "Thriller", "Comedy", "Action"
- Subgenre: "Hollywood", "French", "Italian"

If this picture is correct then your design may be wrong as there is no relationship between Movie and Subgenre. That told, try this

```
SELECT movie.title, genre.name 
FROM movie 
LEFT OUTER JOIN movie_genre 
ON (movie.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id) 
JOIN genre 
ON (genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre_subgenre 
ON (genre_subgenre.genre_id = genre.genre_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN subgenre 
ON (subgenre.subgenre_id = genre_subgenre.subgenre_id)
```

Comment: Thank you!, I had not thought about putting a double left outer join, one for movies and the other one for genre. That worked!!!

Comment: I'm going to have another look at the design now that you mention it then to see if it's better to link movies to subgenres, still quite a lot to learn about databases :)